# What is the complexity of binary search tree to sort n elements

Tags: data-structures, binary-search-tree

We are given BST with n nodes which are integer. What will would be complexity to print all integers in sorted order?
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To print in sorted order you would have to go through an in-order traversal of the graph, which is a depth-first traversal.

The time complexity of that would be O(n + m) where n is the number of nodes and m is the number of edges.

Since this is a BST, maximum number of edges would be n - 1 hence the time complexity would be O(n + n - 1) = O(n).